# React-Native Styled-Components Trying to Put Two Different Components in the Same Line

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, styled-components

I tried to put two different components of text in the same line utilizing `Container`, but when I did that, the properties I've set in `GeneralText` and `Information` seem to go way. With the exception of the color I've set for `Information`.

What would be the best way to approach this?

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';


const GeneralText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
`;

const Information = styled.Text`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: grey;
`;

const Container = styled.Text`
  flex: 65px;
`;

const Menu: FC<Props> = () => (
  <Menu>
      <Container>
        <GeneralText>First Name</GeneralText>
        <Information>John Smith</Information>
      </Container>
  </Menu>
);

export default Menu;
```

**What I currently have**

[image]

**What I am trying to accomplish**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change `const Container = styled.Text` to `const Container = styled.View` as well as adding `position: absolute;` underneath `Information`

```
const GeneralText = styled.Text`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 12px;
`;

const Information = styled.Text`
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  color: grey;
`;

const Container = styled.View`
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex: 65px;
`;
```

Answer (score 3):

on the container you have to create a display: 'flex', flex-direction: 'row', justify-content: 'space-between'

Answer (score 1):

can you try to use, justify-content: space-between in container..
I think you'll get your answer. If you still face your problem, lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I just found an answer and will post it soon. But thanks again :)

Comment: No issue... XD..